# Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_FUNCTION' in my MVC framework

Tags: php

I'm following the [Create your First Tiny MVC Boilerplate with PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-your-first-tiny-mvc-boilerplate-with-php/comment-page-2/#comment-358132) tutorial, and as far as I can tell--my code is identical to Jeff's code... yet I'm receiving this error:

> **Parse error:** parse error, expecting
>   `T_FUNCTION' in
>   **D:\wamp\www\MVC_test\application\load.php**
>   on line **8**

**load.php**

```
<?php

    class Load {
        function view( $file_name, $data = NULL )
        {
            if( is_array($data) ) { extract($data); }
        }
        include 'views/' . $file_name;
    }

?>
```

I've tried a few different things, but I don't understand what is wrong with line 8.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This line

```
include 'views/' . $file_name;
```

is inside a class but outside a method, which is not possible in PHP.

Comment: bah, my if statement bracket structure confused me... good little nugget there though. Thanks!

Comment: @Shango no problem. If it's an architectural issue rather than a mere typo (i.e. you wanted to include code that is a part of  the class definition), say so. It's not possible to do that at all in PHP, but there are several workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

$file_name is local variable inside the function can not be used outside it

it's not allowed to write plain code outside the method in the class body

```
//replace
       function view( $file_name, $data = NULL )
        {
            if( is_array($data) ) { extract($data); }
        }
        include 'views/' . $file_name;
//with
       function view( $file_name, $data = NULL )
        {
            if( is_array($data) ) { extract($data); }
            include 'views/' . $file_name;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't include in a class definition with an expression

```
<?php

        class Load {

            function view( $file_name, $data = NULL )
            {
                include 'view/'.$file_name;
                if( is_array($data) ) { extract($data); }
            }

        }

    ?>
```

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : updated.

Comment: @Guarav: The concatenation isn't really the problem either. The `include` is.

Comment: <?php
class a{

var $a = 'a'.'b';
}
$aa = new a();

Comment: @Gaurav: No, you can't initialise class members with expressions. But that's besides the point here. You can't `include` in a class definition with an expression _or anything else_!

Comment: okay, Thanks, I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

This line should be,

```
include ('views/' . $file_name);
```

[php include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: You don't need parentheses (as demonstrated by the page you linked to), and this was not the problem.